# Why youtube API from some channels return wrong views statistics?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube api, but I saw some channels return wrong statistic views number.

Example: https://www.youtube.com/user/LuisFonsiVivo/about

API CALL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=topicDetails,snippet,brandingSettings,statistics&key=API_KEY&id=UCxoq-PAQeAdk_zyg8YS0JqA

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think you or the library you are using is turning the unsigned long `10,599,143,493` into an integer (UINT_MAX `4,294,967,295 `). The overflow is resulting in `16,345,349`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) returns a list of [channelsResource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource)

> statistics.viewCount   unsigned long
>   The number of times the channel has been viewed.

Dummy [Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCC-is3jc3SUfR6rNobLGSzQ/about)

[image]

Response from api  [test here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatistics&id=UCC-is3jc3SUfR6rNobLGSzQ&_h=1&)

[image]

I suspect you are looking at the views for a video.

Comment: He is viewing the channel page, the channel viewCount and the API request is also about the channel. He is not looking at the views of a video (look at the link he provided).

Comment: @jodacame could you add a little explanation on what you did wrong? Or, how you changed the request in your question to deliver the correct results.